# Parent an object without inverse but keep transforms

Tags: rigging

I'd like my child object to inherit the space of it's parent. By that I mean that when zeroed out the child object moves and rotates to it's parent's position and rotation. But I don't want the object that is becoming the child to move it's new parent's position and rotation when I create the parent child relationship.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you select the child first, then the parent and hit CTRL+P in the 3d view, there are a few options. Non of them helps?

Comment: The Object(Without Inverse) is the option that results in the behaviour I want. But Blender zeroes out the child's transforms. I want it to stay where it is.